# Raid5 Deleted and Recreated with disks in different order

Tags: ubuntu, raid

I have a 4 raid 5 array that I used as /home on a linux server running the Zentyal (Ubuntu 12.04based) server packages. I could not get the raid recognised on the Zentyal package so when installed Zentyal on a new server I deleted the md0 array and created a new array. I didn't check that the disks where in the same sequence as the original server. When I rebooted at the end of the install the array was resync'd.
Now I have a clean install but no data visible. Can I get the data back through mdadm or testdisk.

Thanks for any assistance

Comment: You need to tell us how you did it (the commands you executed). Did you mount it and find it empty?

Answer (score 0):

The order may not be the problem here, mdadm should be able to handle it. , but if your array was being resynced, you may have lost your data. You should have tried creating your new array and force the resync not to be done, assuming you have a clean array already :

```
man mdadm
[...]
       --assume-clean
              Tell mdadm that the array pre-existed and is known to be clean.  It can be useful when trying to recover from a major failure as you can  be  sure  that  no  data will be affected unless you actually write to the array.  It can also be used when creating a RAID1 or RAID10 if you want to avoid the initial resync, however this practice — while normally safe — is not recommended.   Use this only if you really know what you are doing.
[...]
```

Now that resync is done, you can try and see what testdisk it showing, but I wouldn't expect too much of it, sadly.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have checked the array with testdisk and you are correct there is nothing on the disks. So it looks like all the data is gone.

Comment: When you *create* an array the order is highly important.

Comment: An update. I found nothing on the array with testdisk but am currently running PhotoRec on the new array and it is finding the files. So it looks like I will recover most of the data!

Comment: That's a good news! You're lucky :) --assume-clean will be for next time then ;)